# Chrome Extension - checking for newer version at runtime

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am wondering if there is a query we can run, to check if there is a new version of a particular Chrome Extension, using the `window.chrome` object?

I am guessing something like:

```
chrome.runtime.getPublishedVersions();  // made up call
```

Is there some way I can notify users of my extension that they should update to a newer version?

I can get the current version with

```
chrome.runtime.getManifest().version;
```

but I wondering if I can do something like:

```
chrome.runtime.getNewestPublishedVersion(); // made up call
```

then compare them, if the newest published version is different, I want to alert the user, so that they can install the newer version.

Comment: Are you asking about content script update or extension code in general? Because from the [`doc`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/hosting): Extensions are automatically updated without user intervention, just like the Chrome Browser.
To update an extension, the version number will need to increase in the manifest

Comment: Extensions are updated automatically? Are you sure? seems like users have to go to `chrome://extensions/` to update them? idk

Comment: Chrome has an automatical system of extension update, I'm sure about it. It's not instant and Chrome checks for a new version once in some period of time. If you want an instant update to a new version - you need to do request to the ChromeStore and check your version with a version from the store.